# How reboot PC from the installation dialogs, using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-10

I have inserted a USB stick with Windows 10 install files on it and have turned on the PC. It has booted, and in the installation I have chosen to go into the command prompt to use diskpart for something.

How do I restart the PC now from keyboard?

shutdown /r does not work, the command doesn't exist in that console.
There's no big tile that says "restart PC". Only "Turn off you PC". It turns it off indeed.
ALT+CTRL+Delete does nothing.

Comment: Not sure, but is it because I wiped C: and the console looks for the shutdown command there?

Comment: Type `exit` and push ENTER.

Comment: @Appleoddity This closes the console.

Comment: Yes, returning you to other options. One of which should be a method to restart. Exiting setup at the very least reboots the computer.

Comment: There is none. I guess there could be a hardware problem that makes Windows not give me any restart button, but I don't know.

Comment: Can you clarify "exiting setup"?

Answer (score 0):

Try ALT+F4. If nothing pops up then im afraid you have to turn off your pc and start it again

Comment: Thanks! Well, unfortunately, I have tried ALT-F4 already and there comes nothing that would allow me to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

At the Command Window you can type `exit` and press ENTER. Or, click the Red X in the upper right hand corner to close the Command Prompt window.

[image]

Once the command prompt window closes you are returned to the previous menu:
[image]

- Choose `Continue` to REBOOT the PC
- Choose `Turn off your PC` to POWER DOWN the PC